# CSS imported by a dependency

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am working on a Nextjs/Express with TypeScript application and when I added the MDEditor component to `pages/sheets/text-editor.tsx`:

```
import MDEditor from "@uiw/react-md-editor";

const TextEditor: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MDEditor />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextEditor;
```

I got the following error:

> ./node_modules/@uiw/react-markdown-preview/lib/esm/styles/markdown.css
> Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules. Read more:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-npm Location:
> node_modules/@uiw/react-markdown-preview/lib/esm/index.js

I believe it's because I added Tailwind to this project via this documentation:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

What is going on here?